# how to print all lines in a file which has certain field less than some input value

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a file file_name with lines as follows:

```
line1: Order='O1', ProductDetail: [Product='P1', Weight=100, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P2', Weight=90, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P3', Weight=110, Unit=Kg]
line2: Order='O2', ProductDetail: [Product='P1', Weight=100, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P2', Weight=100, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P3', Weight=110, Unit=Kg]
```

Expected output:

```
line1: Order='O1', ProductDetail: [Product='P1', Weight=100, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P2', Weight=90, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P3', Weight=110, Unit=Kg]
```

Ideal expected output:

```
line1: Order='O1', [Product='P2', Weight=90, Unit=Kg]
```

I need to print all lines for any product whose weight is less than 100. How will I achieve that?

Comment: if the weigh is less than 100, will it start with 0? my question is the length of the field 3 always or can it be 2 or 1? l

Comment: @EdMorton - I have added expected output. Thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a not-so-robust approach is:

```
$ awk -F'[ =,]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) 
                    if($i=="Weight" && $(i+1)<100) 
                       {print; next}}' file

line1: Order='O1', ProductDetail: [Product='P1', Weight=100, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P2', Weight=90, Unit=Kg], ProductDetail: [Product='P3', Weight=110, Unit=Kg]
```

set delimiters based on the structure of your input file, find the search tag "Weight" and check the value in the next field (due to `=` delimiter).

Answer (score 0):

Another way with awk :

```
awk '
  {
  i = split ( $0 , a , /Weight=/ )
  for ( j = 2 ; j <= i ; j++ ) {
    sub ( /,.*/ , "" , a[j] )
    if ( a[j]+0 < 100 ) {
      print
      next
      }
    }
  }
' infile
```